# Trasparent intro overlay to introduce user the app

Tags: java, android

I was wondering to create something like a setup wizard for when the user first starts my app. This is needed due to the complexity of the app to help the user. Searching for something like this I found a library that isn't a setup wizard, but lets you point an element on the screen and give some info about it.

The library is this [link](https://github.com/amlcurran/Showcaseview). (Showcase View Library by Espin)

I'm able to show one indication using this, but I can't concatenate more than one indication, you know, the first is shown, you pulse next and goes to the nex indication, this way until you arrive to the end and pulse finish.

[image]

Looking for any tutorial or step-by-step guide that could help me doing this, I found one, but it was done with old code, and the newest version of the library has some changes that doesn't fit the example. I've tried modifiying the code of this example to match with the new version of the library, but I don't get to view the indication one by one, I just get all them overlapped.

This is the link to the library's ShowcaseView class where all this logic is defined: [ShowcaseView.java](https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/github/amlcurran/showcaseview/ShowcaseView.java)

And this is how the doc says to implement it ot your app:

```
new ShowcaseView.Builder(this)
    .setTarget(new ActionViewTarget(this, ActionViewTarget.Type.HOME))
    .setContentTitle("ShowcaseView")
    .setContentText("This is highlighting the Home button")
    .hideOnTouchOutside()
    .build();
```

Has someone worked with this library and knows how could I concatenate few indications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ### What's missing in v5
>
> ShowcaseViews: the class which queues up ShowcaseViews in a
>   tutorial-type method. I never really liked this class (generally, you
>   should use SCV sparingly); I'll add it back in based on the Builder
>   class when I can.

So either:

- implement it by yourself and submit a pull request.
- Or wait for the next release.
- Or use v4
- Or submit an issue on github to directly ask the author when this will be released.

Comment: You're right. It seems then that doesn't exist that option by default. I needed for now so I'll see if I can implement by myself